# Create a mapping function depending on type hierarchy

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I have an application that follows *Domain Driven Design* rules. One of the rules of *DDD* is that the domain layer should not depend on the infrastructure layer. I have a tool that checks if there are any dependencies (*imports*) from domain to infrastructure.
In my infrastructure layer, I have a class hierarchy like this:

[image: infrastructure]

In my domain layer, like this:

[image: domain]

Now, I need to map my domain classes to the infrastructure entities in order to save them in my database.

I have an out port in my domain which is an interface:

```java
// infra/ports/out/RuleRepository.java
public interface RuleRepository {
  Rule save(Rule rule);
}
```

This interface in implemented in the infrastructure layer:

```java
// domain/RuleRepositoryJpaAdapter.java
public class RuleRepositoryJpaAdapter implements RuleRepository {

  // extends CrudRepository<RuleEntity, Long>
  RuleCrudRepository jpaRepository;
  RuleMapper mapper;

  @Override
  public Rule save(Rule rule) {
    return jpaRepository.save(mapper.mapToEntity(rule))
      .mapToDomain();
  }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to implement `mapToEntity` without having to check the type of the rule. The best way would be to add a `mapToEntity` method to `Rule`, `IpRule`, `BlackListRule` but this would break the unit tests that check if there is any imports between the domain and infrastructure layer. If there any other way?

What I have right now:

```java
public class RuleMapper {

  public RuleEntity mapToEntity(Rule rule) {
    if (rule instanceof IpRule) {
      return new IpRuleEntity().mapFromDomain(rule);
    } else if (rule instanceof BlackListRule) {
      return new BlackListRuleEntity().mapFromDomain(rule);
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected argument of type " + (rule == null ? "null" : rule.getClass().getName()));
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the [Visitor Pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-visitor-pattern) to implement [double dispatch](https://www.baeldung.com/ddd-double-dispatch).

In this example, it could look something like this:

```
public abstract class Rule {
    // Maps a rule to a result type T
    public interface Mapper<T> {
        T mapIpRule(IpRule rule);
        T mapBlackListRule(BlackListRule rule);
    }

    public abstract <T> T map(Mapper<T> mapper);
    
    // ...
}

public class IpRule extends Rule {
    @Override
    public <T> T map(Mapper<T> mapper) {
        return mapper.mapIpRule(this);
    }

    // ...
}

public class BlackListRule extends Rule {
    @Override
    public <T> T map(Mapper<T> mapper) {
        return mapper.mapBlackListRule(this);
    }

    // ...
}

public class RuleMapper implements Rule.Mapper<RuleEntity> {

  public RuleEntity mapToEntity(Rule rule) {
    return rule.map(this);
  }

  @Override
  public RuleEntity mapIpRule(IpRule rule) {
    return new IpRuleEntity();
  }

  @Override
  public RuleEntity mapBlackListRule(BlackListRule rule) {
    return new BlackListRuleEntity();
  }
}
```

It has a nice property that there is compile-time check that all subtypes are handled correctly. If a new subtype of `Rule` is added later, it will need to implement the `map` method, which will require adding a method to the `Rule.Mapper` interface, which in turn will require the `RuleMapper` implementation to implement that method. In the example given in the question that uses runtime type checks with `instanceof`, it's possible to miss a case, resulting in an `IllegalArgumentException` at runtime.

However, you will need to judge whether the extra complexity is worthwhile for your specific situation. It might be that your existing `RuleMapper` is just fine.